# Interpreting the summary() of a lm() linear model in R

Tags: regression, r, multiple-regression, p-value, r-squared

I have a multiple linear regression with 4 independent variables. The `summary()` function returns the following:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.03039    0.16152  -0.188   0.8530    
var1         -0.96553    0.18595  -5.193 7.34e-05 ***
var2        -0.25014    0.19732  -1.268   0.2220  *  
var3         -0.40355    0.22072  -1.828   0.0851 **  
var4         0.15887    0.18559   0.856   0.4039    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5606 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7572,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6857 
F-statistic:  10.6 on 5 and 17 DF,  p-value: 9.445e-05
```

It shows that var4 is not significant. However, when I remove it from the model, the new $p$-value increases, $R^2$ decreases, and the mean squared error (MSE) of the model also increases.

Question: Should I keep or remove `var4` from the model? Will my model be criticized if I keep a non-significant independent variable?

Comment: Adding a variable ALWAYS reduces MSE thus increases R^2 and R^2 is inversely proportional to SSE. Use the adjusted R^2 to determine as to whether to include the variable or not. ie if the adjusted R^2 changes by alot when the variable is added/removed, then include the variable, otherwise leave it out

Answer (score 3):

Onyambu is correct that adding variables always increases $R^2$ (technically, I think it can have no effect, but that doesn't happen in practice). But adjusted $R^2$ is by no means the only criterion (see AIC and BIC and Mallows Cp for instance) and  there are many reasons for including a non-significant variable:

- It may be part of your hypotheses
- It may be part of "theory"
- There may be little power in the study (due to inadequate sample size)
- It may be an important control (e.g. it may have important effects on other parameter estimates or their standard errors.

Will your model be criticized? That could happen either way. You want to have defenses to the criticism and reasons for your choices, and those go beyond $R^2$, adjusted or not.